# Review features: quality answer criteria?

Tags: discussion

There's a high number of questions I see from time to time that have a high number of upvotes, but may be totally against the grain of common best practices such as Don't Repeat yourself, hard-coding constants into the logic, mixing the logic with the data, or other weird oddities that the programming community is trying to pull away from.

My concern is that we'll allow low-quality code to propagate in the hands of inexperienced programmers because they have no warning or indication to what more experienced programmers think of the code. They see up-votes, they see accepted, they see "this is good."

**Would it be worthwhile to devise a means by which we could review highly-trafficked questions for *quality* determined by the experienced in addition to to being *correct* as chosen by the asker?**

Comment: Seems like these features are already in place. See: [How can we utilize the "Greatest hits" list for our sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103650/how-can-we-utilize-the-greatest-hits-list-for-our-sites), and [How aggressively should we maintain and improve very popular questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103053/how-aggressively-should-we-maintain-and-improve-very-popular-questions)

Answer (score 3):

Without having to have a system in place to do what you propose (which I'm not for or against), one of the best things to do is comment on the bad answers.

Even better in that regard would be to provide an alternate answer which highlights the good habits you are trying to put forth.

It's not a blanket solution, but it works in the interim, and if we all did a little of this here and there, it would add up.

Comment: I was pondering adding a checklist of criteria each SE site could decide upon. For instance, this code is reusable, clean, well documented, low bugs, great advice, etc... That approach would mean you don't add answers, but at-least there's feedback (less work), and anyone who wants to add the higher-quality answer is still free to do so.

Comment: @Incognito Some of those might be difficult to pin down, as they are highly subjective in and of themselves.  Conscientious voters probably already take some of this into consideration.  I think what this would amount to is taking each person's snippets and putting them through a code review, which might become a barrier to answering questions.  I do like your idea, but you'd probably have to flesh some more specific sample criteria out so others can see where you are coming from.

Comment: Right, it's a hard thing to come up with, which is why I'm wondering if it's a worthwhile endeavor in the first place -- not a call for full solutions.