# How can we utilize the "Greatest hits" list for our sites?

Tags: discussion, post-feedback, greatest-hits

We have been trying to figure out ways to utilize [anon feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99370/what-should-we-do-with-anonymous-user-feedback). One idea was to use the information to **find** questions that are disproportionately popular with the anon and low rep users (aka. The Long Tail).

In particular, look for questions that got a large number of anonymous feedback in relation to the total number of views. These posts are ideal candidates for [aggressive maintenance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103053/how-aggressively-should-we-maintain-and-improve-very-popular-questions).

We introduced a page on each site with some preliminary work:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits

This list comes in 2 flavours. You can get a global list, or filter it down to questions you answered. (This allows you to gauge feedback on your own posts)

[image: your stuff]

---

The algorithm works in the following way:

1. Look at all questions with more than the median amount of views that are older than **3 months**, excluding closed and locked questions.
2. Sort by a modified "Views Per Day" which factors in unique anonymous and low rep feedback provided.

Views Per Day: If a post is 30 days old and it has 30 views, we consider it to have 1 view-per-day. This allows us to treat old and new questions slightly more equally.

---

The philosophy is that questions on the top of the list deserve some extra "love" cause they are the site's "face" to the public.

1. Can you think of any ways to improve the "greatest hits" algorithm?
2. How can we utilize this information to better our sites?
3. Do we need any "engine level" changes to allow for improving a question/answer set?

Comment: It would be nice to see that same personalized information (ie the anonymous feedback) on each of one's answer. But I suppose you are still exporing how to take advantage of those data.

Comment: Are you counting *all* views, or just anonymous views?

Answer (score 7):

Allow Tag Filtering, like you do on the Review page, so people can work on what they know.

> or click the tags in the sidebar to narrow and filter.

I like that you have pagination, which is what Review is desperately missing.

Also, on Meta I'd filter out those with moderator tags.

Comment: review will paginate, ironically enough, once you select a tag to filter review down some. Perhaps try that first? :)

Comment: @Jeff, didn't know that, as I actually haven't been using Tag Filtering myself on the Review page.  I just hate to have to keep hitting that '30 more' link.  But now that I check it out, I seem to be stuck on having it filtered by tag, how do you go back to tagless?

Comment: @Jeff, I found after I went to a second tag, that the tag then showed up in the URL, and I could directly edit it to get back, but it doesn't seem like good UI to have to do that.

Comment: I went into review today, and there were pages.  It was so nice to be able to set my post count to 50 per page.  I hope this is a permanent change, thanks.

Comment: no idea what you're talking about; it's the same as I said above -- you have to filter down to 90 or less to get pagination. So click those tags yo.

Comment: Well, there were only 87 I think, so maybe you guys had reset the review page OR changed the "low quality" algorithm, so then it ended up paging.  Guess I'll keep dreaming.

Answer (score 5):

I for one would prefer to *see questions that are disproportionately popular with the anon and low rep users* listed in one of the tabs at [review screen](https://stackoverflow.com/review/). Because of mentioned *disproportion* I would rather have this tab called "Greatest misses".

That way would be convenient to me to inspect these questions and up/downvote/flag as needed to re-evaluate these questions from my perspective.

- to avoid misunderstanding - I wouldn't want to review *all* the high-view count questions, only the part of those that somehow mis-matches with the voice of trusted sub-community. Say,
   
  10K views and single vote - I would want to check how's that? Like questions displayed in [votes tab for high view count](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=views%3a10000) - when last page(s) are selected
   
  500 'helpful' marks and no upvotes at all - I would want to look at that
   
  etc

Basically I'd want to somehow balance *disproportional popularity* with heightened attention from reviewers.

[image: imaginary screen shot]

Comment: Heh, "greatest misses." Perhaps you would be interested in [a similar question that I had about them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102786/162705) vis-à-vis the weekly newsletter?

Comment: it'd be identical to view count, really

Comment: @JeffAtwood _view count_ what's that? tabs in my review screen are "first answers, low quality posts, first questions, late answers", nothing else

Comment: @JeffAtwood I think I figured it. No it's not identical. I'll update my answer to clarify that

Comment: still the same as sorting by view count, since anon feedback is absolutely linear by viewcount. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A50000 and so forth..

Comment: @JeffAtwood I see. At the search you gave, answers with more than 10 votes are not those I'd want to review ([views:50000 + votes:10](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A50000+%2B+votes%3A10)). I tried to hack search to something like _views:50000 + not votes:10_ - this gave me empty results. Any idea on how to get there?

Answer (score 4):

I had a small amount of rep on "gaming".  I set a bounty which took me down to 3 (or maybe 5?).

That's too low to do anything, but I still get asked if I found this answer useful [YES] [NO].

I suggest, politely, that my votes should be filtered out of your anon feedback stuff.  Because i) I'm  registered user, on a few SE sites, not a real anon.  and ii) I'm too dumb to set a sensible bounty level and so do you really want to include my opinion on anything?

Answer (score 3):

- **Could you clarify what the zeros mean?**  The tooltip says:

[image: Zero Votes]

So users voted if it was Useful? **Yes + No = zero?** or **Zero Yes votes?**  Note:  I'm not talking about votes for the [greatest hits I've participated in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits?userId=152009).  I'm a noob.  I've made a minimal contribution.  I'd *expect* to see zeros.  I'm referring to the < https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits > page which has zeros on the first page.

- <strike>The '**worst-hits**' would also be useful -- perhaps as a **moderator only** page -- to identify questions which could be deleted or contain outdated information.</strike> <-- it's in the moderator tools.  Cool.  I'm not there yet.  Thanks waffles!
- And yes, it's silly to even include this, but [the 21st page is blank](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits?page=21)...

Comment: We already have least helpful btw ... in the 10k tools http://stackoverflow.com/tools/post-feedback/least-helpful?filter=all

Comment: sorry only counting distinct upvoter ips in this context ... downvotes are ignored