# How can I find questions that are eligible for a bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounties

Let's say I've got [more rep points than you need](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118398/how-can-i-make-use-of-excess-reputation-points), and that I want to put bounties on lots of questions. How would I best go about this?

Looking at the tabs of the "Questions" section (`newest faq votes active unanswered`) often gives me questions that are too new, because I can only put a bounty on a question once it's two days old.

**What's the best way to find questions that are not closed, and >=2 days old, and preferably without accepted answers?**

Comment: Bah. Hippie! The point of rep is to hoard it and make it more. So in the end, we all sit in our chairs like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/ScroogeFirst.jpg).

Comment: @Pekka'sOrganicRepFarm You have an *organic* rep farm, and *he's* the hippie...right =)

Comment: @jadarnel maybe the Farm is only a small part of my portfolio, which *could* include a large nuclear rep plant as well!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to search by the age of a question.  The best I can come up with is to search for questions that are `closed:0` and `hasaccepted:0`, then go to the **newest** tab to put them in order.  After that it's a quick manual search to find where the questions older than 2 days start.

**Meta Example:** https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=hasaccepted%3a0%20closed%3a0

**Parenting Example:** https://parenting.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3a0%20hasaccepted%3a0

Note: Do an empty search to bring up the [advanced search options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps at least the first few of those `newest faq votes active unanswered` tabs aren't all useless for this purpose.

I discovered that I can just skim through these lists and ignore those that are marked `closed` or have an accepted answer as indicated by the answer count (indication varies according to site design).

This doesn't take into account questions that already have bounties on them though, so when I click through to ones that I think are candidates, some might already have (had) a bounty. So this isn't foolproof, but it's a start.