# Badge proposal: "famous answer"

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-request

I'm making this proposal since I have this answer (accepted) on a question that has almost 7K views and counting: [Javadoc @see or {@link}?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10097199/1313143)

But I only have 16 upvotes. Currently that's 1 upvote per 430 views, which is a little low in terms of appreciation in my opinion. People are probably finding this question via Google, and they either have no SO account or will not bother to make one.

Therefore I propose the badge "famous answer" (other suggestions for the name are welcome) with the following criteria (again, suggestions to improve these are welcome):

- Your answer is accepted
- Your answer has at least (10|15|20) upvotes
- The question has 10K+ views

Other possible idea:

- Answer is accepted + 20 upvotes **OR** (50|75|100) upvotes

Let me know what you think. Oh and this badge should probably be gold, but at least silver.

Comment: If an answer has many views but few votes presumably people just don't find it that impressive.

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm referring specifically to people who find this on Google. You have actually helped those people too but they can't upvote because they have no account.

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester 1) how do you know they found the answer useful? maybe they just came for the question 2) there is a method for non-registered to vote. they can mark an answer as "helpful". AFAIK, this information isn't used for anything at all, yet.

Comment: @Jeff Where can I find more information on the "helpful" mechanism?

Comment: @BlackVegetable - [Details of the initial implementation are here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing). I'm not sure if it still exists. If it does the UI has changed since then. It is used for the [greatest hits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103650/how-can-we-utilize-the-greatest-hits-list-for-our-sites)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Isn't it kind of a bad sign for an answer to be viewed 7000 times but only manage to reap a handful of upvotes on it?  Doesn't that make it *really* mediocre?  There's nothing badgeworthy in this.

Furthermore views have more to do with the question than the answer.  The answer shouldn't really be rewarded just for receiving views.  IMO "great answer" badges are already a little broken since they actually mean "decent answer on a famous question."

Yes, you have a good point that your answer has probably helped many people who haven't bothered to upvote.  But conversely, maybe your answer has been completely useless to 7000 people.  Our system isn't savvy enough to tell this from views alone.  That's where *upvotes* come in.  Check out my [1k+ view question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11109638/1339987) for a great example of a highly viewed but completely unhelpful answer.  And you want this to receive a *badge*?

Comment: That's probably one way to look at it but I'm referring specifically to people who find this on Google. You have actually helped those people too but they can't upvote because they have no account.

Comment: You can upvote without an account - through the "Mark as helpful" button

Comment: @RoryAlsop - You can't AFAIK. I don't see any such option when viewing SO in incognito mode.

Comment: @RoryAlsop - Or do you mean clicking the up arrow is still recorded? It used to be a separate "this post was helpful" link but now clicking the arrow when not logged in puts up a login dialogue. I assumed it was no longer counted.

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester or maybe you've been completely unhelpful to all of these people.  We shouldn't err on the side of "you might have been helpful" when awarding a badge.  FTR I think this problem exists in badges like famous question, but I don't want more of a bad thing.

Comment: [Anonymous users have not found that question very helpful, either.](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/73917/anonymous-feedback-for-a-specific-question-and-its-answers?PostId=10097199)  Users may arrive via Google, but they don't appear to be impressed any more than registered users.

Answer (score 20):

I dislike this proposal. A famous *question* having an accepted answer doesn't make the answer famous itself, or even correct.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: True, but if it has a certain number of upvotes it is credible. People who find this question don't come here for the question alone, they want the answer. Bet you have found answers on SO a lot by using Google.

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester I've always been fuzzy on when to reply on meta with a comment vs an answer. Why should this be a comment?

Comment: because it's your opinion. An answer on this would be "this will never be implemented".

Comment: This is meta, though - so things are a bit different

Comment: Sparr, your answer is fine as an answer. @Mario: no, that's not how things work here.

Comment: my general approach on meta is comments are for anything that would/should result in the question being edited, and answers are for responses to the question