# How does a lay user of an SE site ever get to the Greatest Hits page?

Tags: discussion, greatest-hits

I was recently made aware that there is such a thing as a "Greatest Hits" page for SE sites, due to [this kerfuffle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375081/196834). But - isn't it effectively a secret easter egg? Are lay,
regular users ever directed there?

Just wondering what that mechanism is supposed to be about, this is not a criticism of its existence.

Comment: [Sample 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits). [Sample 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits). Exactly 1000 questions (20 pages of 50 questions per page).

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum: I don't understand your comment :-(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TL;DR: they don't.

It's one of the [unlinked pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76566/295232) on Stack Exchange. To [quote Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243010/295232):

> This was never linked to from within the UI, because... Well, [we weren't sure what to do with it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103650/how-can-we-utilize-the-greatest-hits-list-for-our-sites).

Six to eight years later, it seems they still don't know what to do with it, except [trying out design changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375081/295232). It was a decent idea to use it as a sandbox, but unfortunately it turned out not to be representative for the other screens...

Comment: "It was a decent idea to use it as a sandbox" <- A sandbox with no visitors. Sure, that's legitimate.

Comment: They did list "Low user impact" as a plus for choosing that screen for testing...

Comment: @bobble: When we cannot tell serious claims from tongue-in-cheek phrases, the situation is pretty dire.