# Why am I not gaining reputation from this answer?

Tags: support, reputation, edits, community-wiki

I wrote the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113254/metamorphic-code-examples/11814102#11814102) a long time ago. It recently had a bounty placed on it to receive more attention. My answer was up-voted `4` times, from `8` to `11`, but my reputation did not increase. Could anyone explain why this occurred?

Comment: You've edited it 10 times and it was auto-converted to community wiki.

Comment: WHAT!?!?!? I tried to make the answer more presentable and update it with better information and I am suddenly NOT rewarded for my efforts, because I tried to hard... to frequently...?

Comment: @awashburn you can flag it for unwikification

Comment: You can flag for a moderator and request it be removed, but in the future, try not to make so many minor edits to your answer. Adding a few words and bolding some text could easily be combined with other, more substantial edits.

Comment: @awashburn The auto-wikification is to prevent people from constantly editing questions to draw more attention to them. Each time you edit your post, it is bumped back to the top of the active question listings. Continuing to improve your posts is great, just try to make fewer larger edits instead if possible.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for the explanation, I was not aware of this 'feature'. I will make more substantial edits in all future posts.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179746/should-authors-be-encouraged-to-maintain-their-answers

Comment: What made you choose "bounty" tag for that question???

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is a Community Wiki; you don't gain anymore reputation since the moment it becomes a CW, not even when the answer is accepted from the user who asked the question.

The only users who can change back a post to not CW are moderators. Flag the answer for moderation attention, and if the moderators notice your edits really improved the answer, they will remove the CW from the post.
I am not sure you will get back the reputation from the votes given when the answer was CW, though.

Comment: If I request an reputation recalculation, would I gain the reputation back?

Comment: I think not: The votes result cast when the post was CW, and those don't change your reputation.