# What should I do with a question that is attracting opinions, but isn't asking for opinions / is asking for factual information?

Tags: discussion, questions

Let's say that a question is asked on a site. Several users have posted factual answers, citing specific sources. The nature of the question is well-defined, but the fact is that within the domain, there is a divergence of thoughts on the subject. There are a small number of widely accepted definitions that tend to be available in what can be considered canonical references. Even with a small number of canonical definitions, individual communities within the domain may also define the terms uniquely.

---

As a user, I have a few options, depending on my reputation level:

- Vote to close
- Up / Down vote the question
- Up / Down vote 1 or more answers
- Flag for moderator attention
- Protect the question from answers by anonymous or new users
- Vote to delete the question or answers, if in the proper state

As a diamond moderator, I have a few more options:

- Close question immediately
- Add a post notice
- Lock (with reasons of content dispute, offtopic comments, historical significance, or wiki answer)
- Delete question immediately
- Delete 1 or more answers immediately

Voting to close really isn't appropriate. Every site has a /help/closed-questions page that discuss categories of questions to be closed. Assuming the question is not a duplicate, is on-topic for the community, is clear, and is reasonably scoped, the only remaining reason is primarily opinion-based, but we've determined that this particular question is seeking those answers that are based on facts and references, yet the issue is that people are posting low quality answers. It doesn't seem right to punish the asker due to answerers.

If the question is useful and relevant, I should up vote it. But that doesn't address the answers.

If an answer is useful (in this case, cites relevant facts), then I should up vote it. Opposite, I should down vote answers that just have opinions. But that isn't a huge punishment. Also, it doesn't prevent other people from answering or people voting by popularity or agreement with the answer, as opposed to usefulness.

If a question is protected, then anonymous and new users can't do anything. That's a step in the right direction, but it doesn't cover people with some reputation. On sites now, most people can easily get an association bonus. Protecting is rather minimal and more useful for questions linked to on external sites and highly visible outside the network.

Post notices don't prevent posts. I suspect the "citation needed" post notice would be the most appropriate, followed by the "insufficient explanation". However, that still requires active moderation to maintain the quality standards. Something better would be preferred. But here is a hook that can be used as a basis for a feature request?

Deletion isn't appropriate since it's a useful question.

Locking is more permanent and no reason accurately captures why. The closest would be wiki answer, but it's not feasible to capture the number of good answers into a single meaningful answer. It would also require some level of curation and moderation to ensure that people aren't editing opinion answers into the wiki answer.

---

What should be done in this situation?

There may be room for enhancements to the protection tool to increase the range of protection, automatically generate flags or move new answers into a review queue on protected or post-noticed questions, or create some kind of new tool. But I'm mainly interested in what the right thing to do with the current tool set is, both for users and moderators.

Comment: Note that protection is (counter-intuitively) effective against those with no more than the site association bonus.

Comment: in case if the question is popular, moderators can follow guidance provided by Atwood in [How aggressively should we maintain and improve very popular questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/165773)

Comment: ...as for regular users, they can flag or raise meta post if the question is popular, asking moderators to act per mentioned guidance

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you should do, as a user:

1. Check that the question makes clear what kinds of answers it is looking for and how answers will be evaluated.  Ideally, if this is not already clear, the question would state that it is looking for evidence or reasoning or facts to support the answer -- not just opinions or anecdotes.  If the question doesn't already state that clearly enough, edit the question to state this more explicitly.  Upvote the question if you consider it useful.
2. Downvote the answers that are providing opinions without sufficient evidence.  Optionally, post a comment to this effect as well, explaining that we are looking for answers that can be supported by evidence, facts, data, or reasoning, not just opinions or anecdotes.
3. For answers that are egregiously bad and cannot be rescued by a reasonable amount of editing, flag them as very low quality, so that others can take a look at them.
4. If you have privileges to vote for deletion, vote to delete such answers as well (at your discretion).

As a moderator, you can comment on answers that are solely offering opinions and/or delete them.  If the question is clear that it is not looking for opinions and the question has received other useful fact-based answers, then I think there is a reasonable case to be made for cleaning up the situation by deleting bad answers that are solely opinions -- but use your judgement.  For instance, one plausible approach might be: if you came across the answer because it was flagged, you could either delete it, or post a comment encouraging the community to express their opinion by voting.  If you came across the answer on your own, you could post a comment encouraging the community to express their opinion by voting or flagging if appropriate.

Closing or downvoting or locking the question is not the right solution: if the question is OK but the answers are bad, focus on the answers.

Comment: I'd be uncomfortable with outright deletion of answers unless the community had already taken at least some action to show their dissatisfaction (i.e. there are a number of VLQ flags, or their has already been one or two delete votes). While deletion is beneficial to the site a mod can't be seen to be acting arbitrarily unless they have very clear and obvious grounds for it.

Comment: @slugster, I understand your discomfort, and I think it is perfectly reasonable (and admirable, for a moderator in your position of trust).  In light of the express/explicit expectations for StackExchange that we want answers that provide reasoning or facts or evidence, I think if a moderator chose to delete such answers their actions would be entirely justifiable -- but if moderators feel uncomfortable with that, that is entirely understandable and reasonable as well.  Just my take on it.  Another way is to post a comment and call for community opinions (votes/flags?).

Answer (score 3):

I've dealt with this in two ways in the past:

- for flags raised on the answer I will mark as helpful but advise the flagger to down vote in future rather than flagging<sup>1</sup>. I will then down vote it myself or do nothing more.
- add a post notice, and leave a tab open so I remember to check it in the next couple of days (this gives the user who answered enough time to rectify it)

You are right that there is a bit of a hole in this area. My situation is a bit different to yours - the site I mod has a pattern of new users joining then going on a "comment as an answer" spree, some are definitely only comment quality but some could almost cut it as answers. Now I don't want to scare new users off unless I really have to, nor do I want to lock questions because some new users can be very knowledgeable and shouldn't be blocked from participation.

As you mod on a bigger and more established site I guess the best option is to persuade<sup>2</sup> your members to be more proactive with their reviewing and voting - get the community to do the work so you don't have to.

If popular opinion is driving an answer that is low in technical merit or accuracy to undeserved heights then a comment or post notice is your best option - it's the community that drives the direction of the site and if you don't like the direction then there's not much you can or should do.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Ideally these flags should be declined and I've started doing that, but it's a beta site and I don't want to annoy or alarm users until they've had time to understand the way the system is supposed to work.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>via chat or meta posts</sub>

Comment: Solid answer. As far as the community goes, they are active in reviewing and voting. However, the issue is the constant curation questions require. In the absence of obvious tools to use, some would rather close a question that starts getting opinion answers. To me, though, closing a question only because of some answers it is attracting punishes the asker and gives the wrong idea of what's allowed and not allowed to other members.

Answer (score 3):

> But here is a hook that can be used as a basis for a feature request?

There are two things that come to mind for a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) though they're not well enough formed in my mind to make them such (yet).

#### Quality protection

Questions already have this to an extent. You need a minimum question quality to be able to post a question on some sites.  Extend this to answers.

When a question gets to the point of starting to collect the "well, my company uses bug and defect interchangeably" answers, they are typically that quality... rather low.  Having a configurable quality protection that allows a moderator to select a minimum length and quality score necessary to post an answer.

If the answer isn't up to the threshold, the system prevents it from being posted as an answer.

#### Mod text in the answer

Allow a mod to insert text into the text area that is displayed when answering that the person asking the question will need to remove. Just a bit of a unignorable warning about the question. This is a more "in your face" approach than the mod notices that people seem a bit too easy to ignore.

```
<textarea>
This question is specifically asking for information supported by
documentation. Providing opinions and anecdotes without supporting
documentation may result in the post being deleted until such information
can be provided.
</textarea>
```

I'm sure we would see that in some answers (how often does one see `enter code here`?), but that just makes it easier to identify them.

---

The key thing with these (and what I believe part of the impetus to bring this up on meta) is that when this *isn't* done there are two parties that are affected... the people doing the curation of the post (be it diamond moderation or community moderation) and the person who posted the answer. It takes time from the first group and the second group has a less than ideal experience when posting an answer on Stack Exchange ("my post was down voted and deleted, you guys are means, I guess I'll just go <s>write</s> eat worms").

Proactively preventing the situations that lead to such experiences reduces the on going moderation needed and provides a better user experience.  It also helps avoid the "whenever I search google, I find the interesting questions are closed as [not constructive | too broad | primarily opinion]" messages that pop up from time to time (even if the person has no intention of contributing to them, closing such questions can create the wrong expectations about what is on the site and the type of community that is active there).